# React Material UI Datagrid get index row with colspan

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am working with datagrid Materaial UI and I want to get the index of each row except the rows with colspan, I use renderCell in the column but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const items = [
 { id: 1, item: "Paperclip", quantity: 100, price: 1.99 },
 { id: 2, item: "Paper", quantity: 10, price: 30 },
 { id: 3, item: "Pencil", quantity: 100, price: 1.25 }
];

const rows = [
  ...items,
 { id: "SUBTOTAL", label: "Subtotal", subtotal: 624 },
 { id: "TAX", label: "Tax", taxRate: 10, taxTotal: 62.4 },
 { id: "TOTAL", label: "Total", total: 686.4 }
];

const baseColumnOptions = {
 sortable: false,
 pinnable: false,
 hideable: false
};

const columns = [
 {
   field: "index",
   headerName: "Nro.",
   ...baseColumnOptions,
   colSpan: ({ row }) => {
     if (row.id === "SUBTOTAL" || row.id === "TOTAL") {
    return 4;
  }
  if (row.id === "TAX") {
    return 3;
  }
  return undefined;
 },
 //renderCell: (index) => index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.id) + 1,
 renderCell: (row, index) => {
   if (row.id === 'SUBTOTAL' || row.id === 'TOTAL' || row.id === 'TAX') {
      return row.label;
   }
   return (index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.id) + 1);
 },
 // valueGetter: ({ index, row }) => {
        //     if (row.id === 'SUBTOTAL' || row.id === 'TAX' || row.id === 'TOTAL') {
        //         return row.label;
        //     }
        //     return  (index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.id) + 1);
        // },
},
{
 field: "item",
 headerName: "Item/Description",
 ...baseColumnOptions,
 flex: 3
},
{
 field: "quantity",
 headerName: "Quantity",
 ...baseColumnOptions,
 flex: 1,
 sortable: false
},
{
 field: "price",
 headerName: "Price",
 flex: 1,
 ...baseColumnOptions,
 valueGetter: ({ row, value }) => {
  if (row.id === "TAX") {
    return `${row.taxRate}%`;
  }
  return value;
 }
},
{
 field: "total",
 headerName: "Total",
 flex: 1,
 ...baseColumnOptions,
 valueGetter: ({ row }) => {
   if (row.id === "SUBTOTAL") {
     return row.subtotal;
   }
   if (row.id === "TAX") {
     return row.taxTotal;
   }
   if (row.id === "TOTAL") {
     return row.total;
   }
   return row.price * row.quantity;
  }
 }
 ];

const getCellClassName = ({ row, field }) => {
 if (row.id === "SUBTOTAL" || row.id === "TOTAL" || row.id === "TAX") {
   if (field === "item") {
    return "bold";
  }
 }
 return "";
};

export default function ColumnSpanningFunction() {
 return (
   <Box
     sx={{
      width: "100%",
      "& .bold": {
        fontWeight: 600
      }
     }}
   >
   <DataGrid
     autoHeight
     disableExtendRowFullWidth
     disableColumnFilter
     disableSelectionOnClick
     hideFooter
     showCellRightBorder
     showColumnRightBorder
     getCellClassName={getCellClassName}
     columns={columns}
     rows={rows}
   />
  </Box>
  );
 }
```

I am using renderCell and valueGetter in the first column but I get a error, I have the code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/columnspanningfunction-demo-mui-x-forked-vusp8y?file=/demo.js